# page loader(Activity Indicator) for phonegap+jquery+android mobile applications

Tags: jquery, android, cordova

while wandering in the world of phonegap,android development, I am facing the big issue when loading the external pages from index.HTML.when I click on the link href, I want to show the page loading indicator.

can anyone suggest me the links or exact tutorial for this,that will enable me to achieve this task.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try this:
http://yensdesign.com/2008/11/how-to-create-a-stylish-loading-bar-as-gmail-in-javascript/